# Pinax on Webfaction - manage.py syncdb not finding virtualenv

Tags: django, pinax, webfaction

(pinax09)[user@web213 social]$ python manage.py syncdb

Error: Can't import Pinax. Make sure you are in a virtual environment that has
Pinax installed or create one with pinax-boot.py.

I'm obviously in pinax09 virtualenv which has pinax installed hence I could create a social project with setup_project. However, once I run the syncdb it complains it can't import Pinax. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a problem with Python versions - I've had that on Webfaction before. Try just `./manage.py syncdb`, without the `python`, which should run the correct version.

Comment: Yes, I chmod'd it and then it worked as you suggested. However now I realize there really is a mess with python versions. I'm using 2.7 but pip says it installed virtualenv in 2.6 as well as virtualenvwrapper. How do I make pip install in correct Python version? do I have to reinstall pip also?

Comment: Try starting from scratch by setting up the virtualenv with the `--python=python2.7` option.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is I don't know where scratch is anymore :) I installed virtualenv in 2.7, also reinstalled pip in 2.7 but Pinax is still in 2.6 and pip doesn't want to uninstall it. pip install Pinax
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Pinax in ./lib/python2.6